# \dotfill not working inside w column

Tags: tables, macros, leaders

In this example inserting `\dotfill` inside `wr{3cm}` column gives no result

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|}
\hline
 \dotfill \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hfil
\begin{tabular}{|wr{3.5cm}|}
\hline
 \dotfill \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, the width is the *maximum* width, in your case it is then 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `w` the content is boxed to its natural width before being placed in a container of the specified size, and the natural width of fill glue is 0pt.

It works with `W`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|}
\hline
 \dotfill \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hfil
\begin{tabular}{|Wr{3.5cm}|}
\hline
 \dotfill \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But I'm not sure if we should make it work with `w`, I'll ask Frank:-)

Comment: Our joint conclusion was that it would be more natural if "w" would behave like "W" in this respect. This got implemented and is already available in latex-dev and in fall in the main distribution.